# Mocking vuex action using and Mocha

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

I'm currently testing vuex module specifically actions.

Here's my code: 
**store/modules/users.js**

```
export const state = () => ({
  users: [],
})

export const mutations = () => ({
  SET_USERS(state, users) {
    console.log('Should reach Here');
    state.users = users
  }
})

export const actions = () => ({
  getUsers({ commit }) {
     return axios.get('/users')
        .then(response => {
          console.log('Reaching Here');
          commit('SET_USERS', response.data.data.results)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
  } 
})

export const getters = () => {
   users(state) {
     return state.users;
   }
};
```

Then when I test my actions:

**tests/store/modules/users.js**

```
it('should dispatch getUsers', () => {
    mock.onGet('/users').reply(200, {
      data: {
        results: [
          { uid: 1, name: 'John Doe' },
          { uid: 2, name: 'Sam Smith' }
        ]
      },
      status: {
        code: 200,
        errorDetail: "",
        message: "OK"
      }
    });

    const commit = sinon.spy();
    const state = {};

    actions.getUsers({ commit, state });

    expect(getters.users(state)).to.have.lengthOf(2);
  });
```

when I try to run the test `npm run dev` it shows the console.log from action but from mutation `SET_USERS` it doesn't show the console.log

I'm referring to this documentation which I can use spy using sinon()
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/testing.html

How can I access the `commit` inside action to call mutation `SET_USERS`?

Answer (score 0):

According to sinon docs

> A test spy is a function that records arguments, return value, the value of this and exception thrown (if any) for all its calls. There are two types of spies: Some are anonymous functions, while others wrap methods that already exist in the system under test.

`const commit = sinon.spy();`

That is not the 'commit' from Vuex, you should test your mutation individually

```
actions.getUsers({ commit, state });
```

The commit argument is actually the spy, it will never trigger the mutation.

To test your mutation it could be something like this

```
mutations.SET_USERS(state, mockedUsers)
expect(state).to.have.lengthOf(mockedUsers.length)
...
```

Comment: But why from this documentation? https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/testing.html
it uses sinon.spy() as a commit? if still not possible to trigger mutation using spy can you give an example where I can trigger the mutation from the action?

Comment: Yes, but look at the expect they are doing there, they are not looking for a change in the state, they are looking for the arguments passed to the spy.
`expect(commit.args).to.deep.equal([
      ['REQUEST_PRODUCTS'],
      ['RECEIVE_PRODUCTS', { /* mocked response */ }]
    ])`

Comment: Ok, understood. But what if I would like to test without using spy? Is there a way I can pass commit from test and can dispatch the action then mutate the state? 

The sample you gave is directly calling the mutation and not the action

Comment: You can create a new instance of Vuex in your tests, with your actions, mutations and state, [here is an example](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-vuex.html#testing-a-running-store)